# Почему Mozilla Firefox меняет половину цвета рамки?

Tags: html, firefox, table, color, border

Один и тот же простейший код. В лисе выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в том же самом гугле как надо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда у mf такое затемнение нижней и правой рамки?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="15" bordercolor="#1A00FF" style="background-color: #F7BDCA">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="background-color: white; text-align: left">Вот таблица</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: white; height: 4vh;">
    <th>которую</th>
    <th>каждый</th>
    <th style="background-color: #A0EF8A; padding: 0 8px 0 8px">строить</th>
    <th>боиться</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: `border-style: solid;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение by andreymal

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Задание 5.3</title>
</head>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table border="15" bordercolor="#1A00FF" style="background-color: #F7BDCA; border-style: solid">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="background-color: white; text-align: left">Вот таблица</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: white; height: 4vh;">
            <th>которую</th>
            <th>каждый</th>
            <th style="background-color: #A0EF8A; padding: 0 8px 0 8px">строить</th>
            <th>боиться</th>
        </tr>
</body>
</html>
```